# Android Studio выбор региона построения проекта

Tags: android-studio

Как заставить Android Studio собирать проект от определенного региона (чтобы выбирались нужные ресурсы)? Например в эмуляторе можно было запустить английскую версию проекта или русскую...

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Простой путь таков: В настройках эмулятора изменить язык и перезапустить приложение.

Comment: Настройки в уже запущенном эмуляторе, в настройках андройда (ОС)